# Open a dta file in R

Tags: r, stata

I am trying to open a Stata `.dta` file which is compressed into `winrar` in R. Here are my codes:

```
library(foreign)
setwd("C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Data on oil/Oil discovery")
data <- read.dta("oil_discovery")
```

and I get :

```
Error in read.dta("oil_discovery") : unable to open file: 'No such file or directory'
```

I think that my problem is coming from the assignment of my working directory but I don't know how to manage it.

Comment: Does `read.dta()` promise to decompress?

Comment: Try `rio::import` https://github.com/leeper/rio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the full file name to `read.dta`. This includes the file ending. That is, instead of

```
 data <- read.dta("oil_discovery")
```

you need to write

```
 data <- read.dta("oil_discovery.dta")
```

If there is an additional problem with the compression, I would imagine that the error message will be different. However, `Error in read.dta("oil_discovery") : unable to open file: 'No such file or directory'` very explicitly points out that the current error is that the file `oil_discovery` is not found.

A good way to check if the name or path is causing the error is to use `choose.files()`. That is, run the following line:

```
 data <- read.dta(choose.files())
```

This will open a pop-up window where you can manually select the file. If this works, then the name of the file was misspecified.

Comment: If you are trying to open a file from Stata versions >12, this solution won't work. But there is an other approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075779/not-a-stata-version-5-12-dta-file).

Answer (score 0):

```
library(haven)
```

> data <- read_dta("**.dta")

> View(data)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).