# not a Stata version 5-12 .dta file

Tags: r

I am trying to use existed data in my pc which is `.dta` file.

I'm trying to open it in R using the following command:

```
library(foreign)
mydata<-read.dta(file="C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\data_raw.dta")
```

But there is this error

```
>> not a Stata version 5-12 .dta file
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What command do you use to open it?

Comment: This was my command >> mydata<-read.dta(file="C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\data_raw.dta")

Comment: Well, you obviously are using `read.dta` from the foreign package. It can only read files from Stata version 5 to 12 and your file seems to be created by a version outside that range. Maybe try `read_dta` from the haven package.

Comment: It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Had the same problem and Roland's suggestion of using `read_dta` from the haven package worked!

To reiterate Roland's comment that helped form this solution.
`read.dta` from the foreign package can only read files from Stata version 5 to 12 and your file seems to be created by a version outside that range.

haven's read_dta can read dta files outside of this range.

Comment: Alternatively, in Stata use `saveold` with option `version(12)` and then import in R.

Answer (score 5):

What I want to add about the read_dta is that first you have to install haven, e.g.

```
install.packages("haven")
library(haven)
data <- read_dta("data.dta")
```